# What did Phil Mickelson say about the PGA?

Tags: golf, pga-tour

Phil Mickelson has lost longtime sponsors [KPMG, Amstel Light; Workday](https://www.sportico.com/leagues/golf/2022/mickelson-sponsor-kpmg-flees-lefty-saudis-comments-1234666400/) and [Callaway](https://golfweek.usatoday.com/2022/02/25/phil-mickelson-callaway-pause-partnership-saudi-pga-tour/) paused their endorsement with him. This apparently has something to do with calling out the PGA tour for being greedy over media rights (eg, the PGA Tour received [$30,000 per second](https://www.golfdigest.com/story/phil-mickelson-pga-tour-media-rights-obnoxious-greed) when they played highlights of Phil).

Phil was apparently using a [golf league](https://golf.com/news/greg-norman-saudi-golf-league-10-questions/) led by Greg Norman as leverage toward the PGA Tour. He is disgruntled, so he's forcing change by using this golf league - that makes sense. Competition from other leagues (in pro sports in general) is short-lived, but some changes do take place within the primary league of the sport, so this isn't too farfetched.

So, why the uproar? Why are sponsors dropping left and right over these comments?

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't so much what Mickelson said about the PGA (everybody knows it's a business), but how he is/was prepared to abandon any sense of ethics in order to make money. The damning comments came from [an currently unpublished biography of him by Alan Shipnuck](https://firepitcollective.com/the-truth-about-phil-and-saudi-arabia/):

> We know they killed Khashoggi and have a horrible record on human rights. They execute people over there for being gay. Knowing all of this, why would I even consider it? Because this is a once-in-a-lifetime opportunity to reshape how the PGA Tour operates. [...] And the Saudi money has finally given us that leverage."

While Shipnuck's biography is unauthorised, Mickelson has not denied making those comments.